# Error: No such validator 'required ' exists When I use 2 Form in the same page

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have one Form and then another Form with a <table inside. (Because I have editable rows). The two forms are not nested.

Here is the JS :

```
import { Form, Field , ErrorMessage , defineRule , configure } from 'vee-validate';
import { localize } from '@vee-validate/i18n';
import { required, email } from '@vee-validate/rules';

defineRule('required', required);
defineRule('email', email);


configure({
  generateMessage: localize('en', {
  fields: {
    firstname : {
      required: 'Le prénom doit être renseigné.',
    },
    lastname : {
      required: 'Le nom doit être renseigné.',
    },
    email : {
        required: 'L\'email doit être renseigné.',
        email: 'L\'email est invalide.',
    },
    password : {
      required: 'Le mot de passe doit être renseigné.',
    },

  },
}),
});
```

Here is my template :

```
<template>

  <br/><br/>

  <Form @submit = "submitAddUser">

        <label class = "label">Login :</label>

        <Field name="login" rules="required" value = "l"/>

        <ErrorMessage name="login" />

        <br/><br/>

        <label class = "label">Password :</label>

        <Field name="password" rules="required" value = "d"/>

        <ErrorMessage name="password" />

        <br/><br/>

        <label class = "label">Prénom :</label>

        <Field name="firstname" rules="required" value = "prenom"/>

        <ErrorMessage name="firstname" />

        <br/><br/>

        <label class = "label">Nom :</label>

        <Field name="lastname" rules="required" value = "nom"/>

        <ErrorMessage name="lastname" />

        <br/><br/>

        <label class = "label">Email :</label>

        <Field name="email" type="email" rules="required" value = "a@b.com"/>

        <ErrorMessage name="email" />

        <br/><br/>

        <button class = "btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>

    </Form>

    <br/><br/>

    <Form @submit = "submitUpdateUser">


        <ErrorMessage name="firstname" />

        <ErrorMessage name="lastname" />

        <ErrorMessage name="email" />


    <table id = "table-user" class = "table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" @click = "checkAll"></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Prénom</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user._id">

                <template v-if="user._id == idUserEdited">

                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{user._id}}</td>
                    <td><Field name="firstname" rules="required" v-model = "user.firstname"/></td>
                    <td><Field name="lastname" rules="required" v-model = "user.lastname"/></td>
                    <td><Field name="email" rules="required | email" v-model = "user.email"/></td>
                    <td><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>&nbsp;<button class = "btn btn-primary" @click = "idUserEdited = 0">Annuler</button></td>

                </template>

                <template v-else>

                    <td><input type = "checkbox" class="check" v-model="tabUserIdChecked" :value = "user._id"/></td>
                    <td>{{user._id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td><button class = "btn btn-primary" @click = "idUserEdited = user._id">Modifier</button></td>

                </template>


            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    </Form>
```

Here is the error I got :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'required ' exists.
    at _test (vee-validate.esm.js:907:15)
    at _validate (vee-validate.esm.js:830:30)
    at validate (vee-validate.esm.js:773:26)
    at validateCurrentValue (vee-validate.esm.js:1618:20)
    at setState.errors (vee-validate.esm.js:1630:16)
    at runLatest (vee-validate.esm.js:501:25)
    at Proxy.validate$1 (vee-validate.esm.js:1650:16)
    at vee-validate.esm.js:2691:26
    at Proxy.map (<anonymous>)
    at validate2 (vee-validate.esm.js:2683:64)
```

But of course the required is defined : defineRule('required', required);

Do I need to "define" it in another way, because I use 2 forms that need the same rule ?

When I remove the second form, the one with the table in it, everything works fine.

I use Vue 3 and the last version of VeeValidate 4.

Any idea?

Thanks